# What happens to prophets that have fulfilled their tasks?

Tags: supernatural

In the CW's *Supernatural*, there have been 2 prophets: Chuck Shurly and Kevin Tran.

> Kevin died,

but Chuck simply vanished when he was no longer needed, but what happened to his host (as in the Chuck Shurly before he became a prophet). Did he die? Or was he simply placed on another part of the planet as a different person?

Also, in season 8, Crowley reveals that there are several other prophets-to-be, but can't be until the current prophet is gone.

What is everything that happens to prophets when they're no longer required?

Answer (score 4):

The answer largely depends of whether you accept the significant amount of evidence that Chuck Shurley was not a normal prophet, but in fact, that

> Chuck Shurley was God.

The evidence here includes statements from Eric Kripke and Rob Benedict (the actor who played Chuck), so IMO it's pretty strong. It was never confirmed on-screen, though, so some people dismiss it.

If you believe that theory, of course, what happened to him is obvious: he had done what he needed so he left.

If you don't believe that theory, and assume he's just like every other prophet, then the premise in your question is a bit off. Prophets are not angels, so they are not possessed and don't have vessels. Prophets are born that way, and when one is needed they are called up from the group of waiting prophets. So, nothing happened to the Chuck Shurley from "before" he was a prophet -- there was no "before".

Unfortunately, Chuck Shurley's time as prophet worked very different from Kevin Tran's, so it's hard to say exactly what happened to him. (This, BTW, is a big part of the evidence for the above theory.) As far as we have been told *after* season 6, prophets maintain their role until they die, when the next one is called up. What this means for Chuck is unclear.

If the prophets in *Supernatural* are supposed to be in the same line of prophets as those from the Old Testament, like Isaiah and Jeremiah, most of those are generally assumed to have lived long lives and died of old age, but they continued to be prophets until the end.

Comment: Can you include or link to the statements by Kripke and Benedict that you mention?

Comment: Its not really relevant to the answer, but for the curious, here's a good place to start: http://youtu.be/Ni7uidj9Rx8

Answer (score 0):

Given God's/Chuck's laissez faire attitude (which we explicitly see in Season 11 Episode 20- at least until the end)), one a Prophet has carried out what they need to do, they can do whatever it is they want. In fact, if I recall, Kevin tried to do the same, until Sam and Dean dragged him back.